# Yii2 memory exhaust error

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I uploaded basic Yii2 app to my webserver..
And it shows this error in my error_log

```
[Fri Apr 03 09:57:59 2015] [error] [client 5.133.137.53] File does not exist: /home/mkiwi/public_html/500.shtml
[Fri Apr 03 09:57:59 2015] [error] [client 5.133.137.53] ] [notice] EACCELERATOR(19087): PHP crashed on opline 6 of register_shutdown_function() at /home/mkiwi/public_html/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/Logger.php:121
```

And when I open this file http://myserver/basic/web/index.php it shows this error:

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3319912065 bytes)
```

Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Show your config/web.php pls. Looks like you are using memory cache that may cause usage of memory over limit.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the top of your web.php file (under use statements) - worked for me.

ini_set('memory_limit', '512M'); // or whatever memory limit you want to apply.

Hope that helps.